# What does it mean to be compact in the $w^{*}$-topology?

Tags: general-topology

- What does it mean to be compact in the $w^{*}$-topology?
- How is it related to polytopes unit balls?

Comment: Do you know what the "w^$*$-topology" means?  (I might guess that it's an abbreviation for the "weak-$*$ topology", but I'm not sure.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark if you can explian I'll be greatful

Comment: Weak* topology is normally used in infinite-dimensional spaces (since all reasonable topologies coincide in finite-dimensional spaces).  If by "polytope" you mean something in a finite-dimensional space, then I imagine weak* is of no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $\rm K$ is compact in the $\ast$-weak topology if and only if given any covering of $\rm K$ by $\ast$-weak open sets $(\rm U_i)_{i \in \rm I}$, there exists a finite subset $\rm J \subset \rm I$ such that the $(\rm U_j)_{j \in \rm J}$ is a covering of $\rm K$.

Comment: I suspect the problem OP is having is not the definition of compact, but the definition of $w^*$, and whether the definition of "compact" has any other characterization in this sort of topology

Comment: Seriously? $ $ $ $